# Erro "Call to undefined function" ao chamar função de uma classe

Tags: php

Tenho uma função para converter a data, porém está me retornando um erro que não consegui ajustar:

Segue código:

```
<?php

class Prog{

    private $DtBase;

    public function setdata($DtBase){
        $this->data = $DtBase;
    }
    public function getdata(){
        return convertData($this->data);
    }
    public function convertData($data){
        $data = Datetime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
    return $data->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}

?>
```

Erro ao chamar a function **convertData**:

> Call to undefined function convertData() in Prog.php on line 11

Alguma dica ?

Comment: Uma dica, em inglês `Data` significa "dados" e `Date` significa `dia/mês/ano/etc`, seria interessante usar os nomes assim `convertDate` quando se referir a um dia.

Comment: Sim, esqueci de mudar por que o nome da function antes estava converterData.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em `getData()` você precisa especificar quem é o invocador(dono) dessa função(método), como no caso é o mesmo objeto utiliza-se o `$this`

Mude:

```
return convertData($this->data);
```

Para:

```
return $this->convertData($this->data);
```